# How to add translations for country names in Virtuemart?

Tags: joomla, translation, virtuemart, country-codes

I am setting up a Virtuemart website in German, but when I select a country for my shipping address, the countries show up in English instead of German.

I have tries to configure the country names in the Virtuemart countries configuration, but German translations I have entered there don't seem to work.

**My configuration in Virtuemart Countries for Austria after translating to German:**

[image: Configuration in Virtuemart Countries]

**But the countries still show up in English on the website:**

[image: Countries show up in English]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If translating a country name through the Virtuemart countries menu does not work, you might want to try adding/editing the country translations configuration file.

In the case of German, add or edit the following file:

`administrator/components/com_virtuemart/language/de-DE/de-DE.com_virtuemart_countries.ini`

and make sure it contains the following content:

```
COM_VIRTUEMART_COUNTRY_AUT="Österreich"
COM_VIRTUEMART_COUNTRY_CHE="Schweiz"
COM_VIRTUEMART_COUNTRY_DEU="Deutschland"
COM_VIRTUEMART_COUNTRY_LUX="Luxemburg"
```

To find the translation key for each country, you could check the file that contains the English translations for the country names, which is located at:

`administrator/components/com_virtuemart/language/en-GB/en-GB.com_virtuemart_countries.ini`

The website should now show the countries in German:

[image: Countries in German]